# Why IF parameters doesn't seems like IF parameters?

Tags: javascript

Recently, I came over a script where the if parameters are not evaluated. The code and quantity in the following JScript is not judged on and =, > or < equations.

```js
if (CODE && QTY) {
    // do something
}
```

But as per my understanding, it should be something like this:

```js
if (CODE > 100 && QTY < 200) {
    // do something
}
```

What's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` statement is executed if the statement within the brackets evaluates is [truthy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).

In your first example, `// do something` will be executed as long as `CODE` and `QTY` are truthy values.

This means that both `CODE` and `QTY` are checked that they are **not**:

- `false`
- `0`
- `""` (empty string)
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

It's used more of a validity check to make sure that the variables can be worked with, than a check of the specific values.